# Understanding Quasilimits

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Given a sequence (an), a real number s is called a quasilimit of (an) if, for every
ε > 0 and every N ∈ N, there is an m ≥ N such that |am − s| < ε. We let L (a) denote the set of quasilimits of a = (an).

Let k be any natural number. Give an a = (an) so that L (a) is a finite set of size k. Then, construct an (an) so that L (a) is countable.

Comment: The more common term is partial limit, it is just the limit of some subsequence. For finite L(a) just take a sequence that cycles the same k numbers periodically.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

1) Try to show that the sequence 
$$a_n = n \quad (\mathrm{mod} \text{ } k)$$

has a finite number of quasi-limits.

2) Try to show that the sequence $(b_n)_{n \geq 2}$, where $b_n$ is the least prime number dividing $n$, has a countable number of quasilimits.